# iOS Core Data search speed improvement

Tags: ios, search, core-data

I am struggling improve the search speed of my iOS app which uses core data. Can anyone help or suggest alternative solutions to improve my search speed? I've listed details to my situation below.

**Project Details**

I am currently creating a data reference app which uses core data with a preloaded SQLite database. I want to be able to search on one or more attributes of an entity which could contain over 100000 records and return results quickly.

The best results I have achieved so far(searching still quiet slow though) is to load a view with a search display controller, set the fetch limit(currently 100) for the fetch request of the fetchResultController. I've also used search scopes to simplify the predicates. I do use the 'contains' keyword in my predicates, but I am not sure how to implement the suggestion in session 137 of WWDC 2010 and what keywords I should be storing or how many I should store.

Here is a link to one of my classes,
http://pastebin.com/cHHicc1s

Thank you for your time and help.

Regards
Jing Jing Tao

Answer (score 1):

You may want to normalize an existing attribute as a new attribute then index it.  Remove the "CONTAINS" from your predicate and instead use `>=` or `<` etc values.  Also, normalize the search text so that the comparison balances.  Apple documents all this in the '[Derived Property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DerivedProperty)' example and in WWDC 2010 session # 118 video.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing large searches on attributes, you should create indexes.  You can do this in Xcode when you define the model.  Click on the entity, and right under where you specify the entity name, you can create additional indexes.

Note, however, that you will incur additional file size overhead, and inserts/deletes will also take a bit more time.  But, your searches will be very fast.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, a couple of things, I have created an index on the an attribute I am searching, but since I import my data into the database I am not sure if this affects the validity of the index? I'm using 'contains' in my predicate, I've read that if I am using 'contains' indexes won't help, do you know if that's correct?